# Views.py not recognised by server. Server won't recognise code or raise exceptions for bad code in file

Tags: django, django-views

I'm struggling to show some model objects I've created through the admin GUI.
I can't get them to show on the webpage through my view function.

(edit:)Having done some digging, I've realised that the server won't raise an exception when I break the views.py file (all other files work fine). Why isn't the server reading the views file?

All files are located in /jobboard. Jobboard is listed in INSTALLED_APPS in settings file, and all other files in jobboard work fine.

I've also noticed that I don't have an admin.py in the project folder. Is that normal?

Views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import staff_member_required
from .models import JobPost
from django.utils import timezone


def jobs(request):   
    JobPost.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')

    latest_post_list = JobPost.objects.order_by('-pub_date')

    context = {

        'deadline': deadline,
        'created_at': created_at, 
        'wordcount':wordcount, 
        'jobtaken':jobtaken,
        'JobPost':JobPost,
        'latest_post_list':latest_post_list,
    }

    return render(request, 'jobboard/jobs.html', context=context)
```

URL.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, re_path, include
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from login import views

urlpatterns = [

    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    #re_path(r'^login/$', auth_views.login(template_name = 'accounts/login.html'), name='login'),
    re_path(r'^signup/$', views.signup, name='signup'),
    path('login/', include('login.urls')),
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('jobs/', views.jobs, name='jobs'),
    path('users/', include('users.urls')),
    path('users/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]
```

Directory structure:

```
gpproject
│   ├── db.sqlite3
│   ├── gp.sublime-project
│   ├── gp.sublime-workspace
│   ├── grad
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── Procfile1
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   │   ├── settings.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   │   ├── urls.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   │   └── wsgi.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   ├── settings.py
│   │   ├── static
│   │   │   ├── office.jpeg
│   │   │   └── pics
│   │   │       └── office.jpeg
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   ├── views.py
│   │   └── wsgi.py
│   ├── jobboard
│   │   ├── admin.py
│   │   ├── apps.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── migrations
│   │   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   │   ├── 0002_auto_20180716_1122.py
│   │   │   └── __init__.py
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── tests.py
│   │   └── views.py
│   ├── login
│   │   ├── admin.py
│   │   ├── apps.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── migrations
│   │   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   └── __pycache__
│   │   │       ├── 0001_initial.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   │       └── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   │   ├── admin.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   │   ├── apps.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   │   ├── models.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   │   ├── urls.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   │   └── views.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   ├── static
│   │   │   └── pics
│   │   │       └── office.jpeg
│   │   ├── templates
│   │   │   ├── login
│   │   │   │   └── office.jpeg
│   │   │   ├── loginbutton.html
│   │   │   ├── logoutbutton.html
│   │   │   ├── navbar.html
│   │   │   ├── registration
│   │   │   │   ├── login.html
│   │   │   │   ├── logintut.html
│   │   │   │   ├── password_reset_complete.html
│   │   │   │   ├── password_reset_confirm.html
│   │   │   │   ├── password_reset_done.html
│   │   │   │   ├── password_reset_email.html
│   │   │   │   └── password_reset_form.html
│   │   │   └── signup.html
│   │   ├── tests.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   └── views.py
│   ├── manage.py
│   ├── oldbackupdb.sqlite3
│   ├── templates
│   │   ├── base.html
│   │   ├── footer.html
│   │   ├── Header.html
│   │   ├── index2.html
│   │   ├── index.html
│   │   ├── jobpost.html
│   │   ├── jobs.html
│   │   ├── navbar.html
│   │   ├── oldHeader.html
│   │   ├── sidenav.html
│   │   ├── signup.html
│   │   └── userdropdown.html
│   ├── universities.xcf
│   └── users
│       ├── admin.py
│       ├── apps.py
│       ├── forms.py
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── migrations
│       │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│       │   ├── __init__.py
│       │   └── __pycache__
│       │       ├── 0001_initial.cpython-35.pyc
│       │       └── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
│       ├── models.py
│       ├── __pycache__
│       │   ├── admin.cpython-35.pyc
│       │   ├── forms.cpython-35.pyc
│       │   ├── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
│       │   ├── models.cpython-35.pyc
│       │   ├── urls.cpython-35.pyc
│       │   └── views.cpython-35.pyc
│       ├── tests.py
│       ├── urls.py
│       └── views.py
├── gradproofworkspace.code-workspace
├── index1.html
├── office.jpeg
├── Pipfile
├── Pipfile.lock
├── Procfile
├── README.md
├── requirements.txt
└── runtime.txt
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: There's a syntax error in your `jobs` function.  `context: {` should be `context = {`. Please make sure the code in the question is your actual code running, and that the syntax is valid python. [mcve]

Comment: Also your `JobPost` model doesn't have a `pub_date` field or a `published_date` field, so this code would raise exceptions about that as well.

Comment: Interesting. when i run the server it says 'System identified no issues (0)'.

Comment: The `jobs` view function would raise exceptions at run time, and I think at import time as well, due to the syntax error (unless python interprets it as a type hint?). Are you sure you are not using a view from some other file?

Comment: the views.py and models.py files are both found in .../gpproject/jobboard. I have corrected the `context: {` syntax error now.

Comment: If I delete the `def jobs(request)` function from the views.py file it makes absolutely no difference to the final webpage view. Does that suggest the problem is with that file? Especially given that it wasn't raising an exception for the syntax error...

Comment: Not only are there syntax errors, there are several name errors. You could would not run at all. The fact that you are not seeing an error shows that this code is not even being imported, let alone run. Please post your directory structure, showing exactly where this views file is, plus your URLs.py.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Håken, that pointed me in the right direction. Though more accurately I was just missing this line of code:

`from jobboard import views`

Answer (score 0):

You are not importing the jobs views. In your urls.py, the name `views` is imported from the `login` app only.

```
from login import views
...
path('jobs/', views.jobs, name='jobs'),
```

You can change it like this:

```
from jobboard.views import jobs
...
path('jobs/', jobs, name='jobs'),
```

Comment: It's still a bit of a mystery why your original routing actually works, since presumably there's no `login.views.jobs` view, so you would get an exception when visiting the `/jobs/`.